# Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Что означает такая ошибка?

> Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам необходимо понять, о чем говорится в ошибке, то в первую очередь попробуйте вбить текст в любой онлайн-переводчик.

Получится *примерно* следующее:

> Используйте для разработки неминифицированную версию скрипта,
>   чтобы иметь возможность просматривать полные сообщения об ошибках
>   и дополнительные полезные предупреждения.

Во-первых, проверьте окружение.
Установите режим разработки, если это необходимо (например, при использовании `browserify`):

```
set NODE_ENV=development
```

Во-вторых, проверьте, не подключаете ли вы `react.min.js` вместо `react.js` и подключите корректную версию.

Составлено на основе ответов на вопрос: [React - Minified exception occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586928/react-minified-exception-occurred)